# PHP Child Nodes

Tags: php, domdocument

So I'm trying to iterate through a DOM Document that will look like this:

```
<track rank="1">
    <name>Believe</name>
    <duration>239</duration>
    <mbid>13194c93-89c6-4ab4-aaf2-15db5d73b74e</mbid>
    <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Cher/_/Believe</url>
    <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
    <artist>
        <name>Cher</name>
        <mbid>bfcc6d75-a6a5-4bc6-8282-47aec8531818</mbid>
        <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Cher</url>
    </artist>
</track>
```

Using PHP I can simply do `$tracks = $xml->getElementsByTagName("track");`
And the thing is, for each track I want to retrieve both its name and duration. I am aware of childNodes property but I don't wont to loop them all. Is there any way to access them directly without using a foreach on its children?

Comment: Have you considered SimpleXML for this?  It would be as easy as `$track_names = $xml-xpath('//track/name'); $durations = $xml->xpath('//track/duration');`

Comment: This doesn't work since I'm creating a new SimpleXMLElement. And for each existing track I need to know their values, so I think your way doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where is the problem in generating a new SimpleXMLElement from two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('example.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$tracks = array();

foreach ($xpath->query('//track') as $track) {
  $tracks[] = array(
    'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $track),
    'duration' => $xpath->evaluate('number(duration)', $track),
  );
}

print_r($tracks);
```